# error resource bool fb_auto_log_app_events_enabled

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I had an error when compiling my app
error resource bool `fb_auto_log_app_events_enabled` managed to fix it

add `bool.xml`
to `android/app/src/main/res/values/bool.xml`

the files

```
<bool name = "fb_auto_log_app_events_enabled"> true </bool>
<bool name = "fb_advertiser_id_collection_enabled"> true </bool>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChGRN.png)

Answer (score 8):

This issue shows upon running `ionic cordova build android`, what I did was to add a new file `bool.xml` inside `platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values`

inside bool.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="fb_auto_log_app_events_enabled">true</bool>
    <bool name="fb_advertiser_id_collection_enabled">true</bool>
</resources>
```

then run again:
`ionic cordova build android`

Comment: this happened when I remove the old ionic native cordova-facebook4 plugin and add the new facebook-connect plugin.

Comment: I'm using an ionic capacitor and it's working fine thanks